# Filtering dataframe contents with the occurance of a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
I have a dataframe of the following type,
              Input         Output         Output SE
  0           Rat           Cat               Mat
  1           rat           cat               mat
  2           0             4.8               0.255
  3           3             7.2               0.32
  4           Bat           Cat               Sat
  5           bat           cat               sat
  6           0             1.8               0.275
  7           3             1.7               0.745
```

These values are read from `Excel`.

I want to separate these contents as the following

```
df1=
0            Rat            Cat               Mat
1            rat            cat               mat
2            0              4.8               0.255
3            3              7.2               0.32


df2=

   0         Bat              Cat               Sat
   1         bat              cat               sat
   2         0                1.8               0.275
   3         3                1.7               0.745
```

I am currently using `iloc`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[0:3]
df2 = df.iloc[4:8]
```

Is there an alternative way?
I have a really large dataframe with the same pattern and I want to split the dataframes when two lines of strings occur.

EDIT: Input dataframe reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create a new key by `//`

```
s1=df.Input.str.isdigit()

for x , y in df.groupby((~s1&s1.shift().fillna(True)).cumsum()):
    print(x,y)


1   Input Output Output SE
0   Rat    Cat       Mat
1   rat    cat       mat
2     0    4.8     0.255
3     3    7.2      0.32
2   Input Output Output SE
4   Bat    Cat       Sat
5   bat    cat       sat
6     0    1.8     0.275
7     3    1.7     0.745

d={x : y for x , y in df.groupby((~s1&s1.shift().fillna(True)).cumsum())}
```

Comment: This solution is good. However the number of rows containing numeric values are not always 2. Sometimes , it could be more or less than 2.

Comment: @Natasha will the output always Cat ?>

Comment: @ Could you please explain a bit? Cat?

Comment: I mean Output always first line `Cat`

Comment: No, not always. There could be rows without Cat as well

Comment: I get this error `arr = operator.inv(com.values_from_object(self))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float''

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split as soon as at least 2 lines contain non numeric values, you can just test for that, and then split groups on each new *group leader*:

```
def isnum(ser):
    try:
        pd.to_numeric(ser)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

num = df.apply(isnum)

# df.grp will be 1 if and only if it is the first of a group of at least 2 lines
#  containing non numeric values
df.loc[~(num|(~num.shift().fillna(True))|num.shift(-1).fillna(True)), 'grp'] = 1

# give a different value for each group:
grp = pd.Series(1, df.loc[~(num|(~num.shift().fillna(True))|num.shift(-1).fillna(True)),
                          'grp'].index)
grp = grp.cumsum().reindex(df.index).ffill()
```

You can now use groupby to get a list of the sub dataframes:

```
dfs = dfs = [sub for _, sub in df.groupby(grp)]
```

Comment: `raise IndexingError(key)
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: (Input         True
Output       False
Output SE    False
dtype: bool, 'grp')` I get this error though